# Creating generic table

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a generic and dynamic table where I have columns, rows and an action button at the end of an row. All data is displaying as intended but the header is not displaying over the action button.

[image]

Is there a way to display the header underline over the action button?

Data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1231",
        "name": "Michael",
        "phone": "11223311",
        "medical": "YES"
    },
    {
        "id": "32123",
        "name": "Johnson",
        "phone": "3311323",
        "medical": "NO"
    }
]
```

```
const headCells = [
    {dataIndex: 'id', name: 'ID' },
    {dataIndex: 'name', name: 'Name' },
    {dataIndex: 'phone', name: 'Phone' },
    {dataIndex: 'medical', name: 'Medical' }
];

const Header = ({ cols }) => {
  return cols.map((col) => (
     <TableCell>{col.name}</TableCell>
   ));
}

const Rows = ({ data, cols }) => {
    if (data) {
        return data.map((row) =>
            <TableRow key={row.uuid}>
                {cols.map(col => <TableCell>{row[col.dataIndex]}</TableCell>)}
                    <TableCell >
                            <IconButton>
                                <SearchIcon color="primary"/>
                            </IconButton>
                    </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
       );
    }
    else return [];
};

return(
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
    <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
        <TableHead>
           <TableRow>
             <Header cols={headCells} />
           </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
            <Rows data={data} cols={headCells} />
        </TableBody>
    </Table>
</TableContainer>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add it manually?:

```
const Header = ({ cols }) => {
  return cols.map((col) => (
     <TableCell >{col.name}</TableCell>
   )).concat( <TableCell className='underline-header'>Actions</TableCell>);
}
```

CSS:

```
.underline-header {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are `map`ing over your data columns, but you do not have a column for "actions". You could do what @Enchew says above or you could add another data column

```
const headCells = [
  {dataIndex: 'id', name: 'ID' },
  {dataIndex: 'name', name: 'Name' },
  {dataIndex: 'phone', name: 'Phone' },
  {dataIndex: 'medical', name: 'Medical' },
  {
    Component: () => (
      <IconButton>
        <SearchIcon color="primary"/>
      </IconButton>
    ), 
    name: 'Actions'
  }
];

const Header = ({ cols }) => {
  return cols.map((col) => (
     <TableCell>{col.name}</TableCell>
   ));
}

const Rows = ({ data, cols }) => {
    if (data) {
        return data.map((row) =>
            <TableRow key={row.uuid}>
                {cols.map(col => (
                  <TableCell>
                    {
                      col.Component ?
                        <Component /> :
                        <>row[col.dataIndex]</>
                    }
                  </TableCell>
                )}
            </TableRow>
       );
    }
    else return [];
};

return(
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
    <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
        <TableHead>
           <TableRow>
             <Header cols={headCells} />
           </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
            <Rows data={data} cols={headCells} />
        </TableBody>
    </Table>
</TableContainer>
)
```

Just a different way to approach the problem